# Scrollable tabs style in Android

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-navigation

I'd like to implement a navigation with two layers of tabs, similar to this one:

[image: Double tab navigation]

However I cannot find how to give scrollable tabs this appearance: centered title for the active tab, and the others pushed to the sides, without separator or underlining. I'm pretty sure I've seen this scrollable tabs style before, so I was wondering if it's just a setting or maybe a third party library.

Could anyone help me with this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `ViewPager`'s [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html). That's what you are looking for.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll actually use [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) as I need the interactivity.