# How to have two layer tabs in android?

Tags: android, tabs, layered

I want to implement two layers of tabs like the image below. 
With the use of support library I have been able to make a single layer tab set for all android versions. But since I am new to android and I don't have a good grasp on this I don't know how to make it for two layers. 
I need to support Android 2.2 and above.

image from: 
[Scrollable tabs style in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911953/scrollable-tabs-style-in-android)

[image: image from:]

Any help will save some lives here :)
Thanks in advance.

ps: please remember I'm a beginner in Android and explanations may need to go in details :S